# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt[3]2)$ is a primitive field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I've tried a method similar to showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ is a primitive field extension, but the cube root of 2 just makes it a nightmare.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have to do it explicitly? By the primitive element theorem, finite separable extensions are simple. This extension is easily seen to be finite, and it's separable since it's a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is perfect.

Comment: @BenWest Nuking the mosquito much? Why use a powerful result depending on Galois theory when simple field theory will suffice?

Comment: @Mathmo123: Ya some mosquitoes' bites' are very itchy...

Comment: @Mathmo123 Simple, it's less work for me.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Primitive element theorem for number fields doesn't need Galois theory and can be proven very quickly. In terms of my answer let $p(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha + s \beta)$. We chose $s$ such that $p(\alpha + s \beta - sX)$ has none of the other $\beta_j$s as roots, so its gcf with $p$ is $X-\beta \in K[X]$; so $\beta \in K,$ and then $\alpha = \alpha + s \beta - s \beta \in K.$ This is from Swallow's "Exploratory Galois Theory", theorem 16.2

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a simpler solution.

Let $a = \sqrt{2} \sqrt[3]{2}$.

$a$ is clearly in the field extension and both generators can be generated by it:

$\sqrt{2} = (\frac{a}{2})^{-3}$

$\sqrt[3]{2} = (\frac{a}{2})^{-2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]2$. It's clear that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a subextension of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt[3]2)$. All that remains is to show that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ has degree $6$ over $\mathbb Q$.

You could do this by explicitly calculating the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$, or by observing that
$$(\alpha-\sqrt2)^3=2,$$ which can be used to deduce that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a degree $3$ extension of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Not complete; you still need to show that that cubic is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, or that the cube-root of $2$ is not in that subfield, since $3$ is prime.

Comment: @user21820 Yup. I intended to give the OP an approach to follow, not a complete answer. In any case, the fact it is a degree $3$ extension follows from the fact that $\sqrt[3]2\notin\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Sure I didn't intend to imply that you should give a complete answer, but I thought you should at least briefly sketch the steps, so that the asker doesn't think that what you wrote suffices. That's all! =)

Comment: @user21820 I've changed the language slightly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try to express both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ as rational functions of $a = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2}$. The job is simple and easily done via equation $$(a -\sqrt{2})^{3}=2\tag{1}$$ so that $$a^{3}-3\sqrt{2}a^{2}+6a-2\sqrt{2}=2$$ or $$\sqrt{2}=\frac{a^{3}+6a-2}{3a^{2}+2}\tag{2}$$ and we have $$\sqrt[3]{2}=a-\sqrt{2}$$ and using equation $(2)$ we can replace $\sqrt{2}$ by a rational function of $a$, so that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is also a rational function if $a$. It thus follows that $\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ will equal $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + s\beta)$ if you choose any rational number $s$ that is not $-\frac{\alpha_i - \alpha}{\beta_j - \beta}$ for any of the conjugates $\alpha_i$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta_j$ of $\beta.$

In your case you can take $s = 1.$

Comment: If you go this way, you might as well use the primitive element theorem that just gives the general result?

Comment: @user21820 Yes, this is an explicit form of the primitive element theorem