# equality of two minimal subfields

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory

I am trying to show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2})$ via elementary means. I have shown $\subseteq$  by setting $\theta = \sqrt[6]{2}$  and then noticing $\theta^{3}=\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta^2=\sqrt[3]{2}$.

I am unable to show the reverse inclusion. I have tried using a dimension argument, but unable to complete it.

I would like a dimension argument to the problem, please (none of the answers have a dimension argument)

Comment: Some observations about the dimension argument would be in order if you tried it.

Comment: @hardmath namely the degree of the extension over the rationals should be $1,2,3& or $6$. If the degree is 1 then it should equal the rationals

Comment: One way: Note that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$ (see e.g. [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1715265/12880)), and expand e.g. $(2^{-1/2} + 2^{-1/3})^2$. (I should add, this is not a *good* way in that it's not very illuminating.)

Comment: Okay, on the one hand we have $\theta^6 - 2 =0$, and that's an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.   So it's the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over the rationals, and the dimension of the "larger" field is six over $\mathbb Q$.  Can we find a rational polynomial satisfied by $\theta^3 + \theta^2$?

Comment: In general if $a, b$ are algebraic numbers with $a$ of degree $2$ over rationals then $\mathbb {Q} (a, b) =\mathbb{Q} (a+b) $. You can prove this by noting that any polynomial in $a, b$ can be expressed as a linear polynomial in $a$ with coefficients in $\mathbb {Q}[b] $.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this doesn't count as a duplicate, as the OP asks explicitly for an elementary method.

One elementary method is to show that $$\sqrt[6]2 = \frac1{310}(16x^5 + 6x^4 - 55x^3 - 104x^2 - 2x - 346)$$ where $x = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$.

This is very tedious to do by hand but is perfectly elementary.

How do I find it? For $i = 0, 1, \dots, 5$, I write down $x^i$ as a $\Bbb Q$-linear combination of $\sqrt[6]2^j$ for $j = 0, 1, \dots, 5$. This results in a system of linear equations, from which I can solve for $\sqrt[6]2$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the comment.

Since $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1715265/12880)), we can use $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ individually (in field-legal ways!) to try to construct $\sqrt[6]{2}$.

One way to do this: since $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ are in our field, so are their inverses, and
$$ \Bigl( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}} \Bigr)^2 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{2/3}} + \sqrt[6]{2} .$$
Hence
$$ \sqrt[6]{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{2/3}} - \Bigl( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}} \Bigr)^2 $$
and the right-hand side is in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$.

**Edit.** As WhatsUp rightly points out, $\sqrt[6]{2} = \sqrt{2} / \sqrt[3]{2}$ is a far prettier manipulation!

Comment: If you already know that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[3]2)$, then isn't it easier to write $\sqrt[6]2 = \sqrt 2 / \sqrt[3]2$?

Comment: Very good point! Your eye is better than mine.